# how to put arguments in docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and maybe this is a stupid question to ask, but how to put arguments to docker compose?
For example, I have:

`docker run --name solr_test -d -p 8983:8983 solr:8 solr-demo`

And I want to create Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  solr_test:
    image: solr:8
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
```

The same thing apply for

```
docker run -dt --net=host --name=web_server cloudsuite/web-serving:web_server /etc/bootstrap.sh 131.155.35.54 arg2 arg3
```

I don't know where to put the solr-demo or these /etc/bootstrap.sh in the docker compose file.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those `solr-demo` and `/etc/bootstrap` already in the container?

If so, if they are already in the container, maybe the `command` would be enough for what you want:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  solr_test:
    image: solr:8
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
    command: solr-demo
```

If those `solr-demo` and `/etc/bootstrap` are external to the container, living ate the host, maybe we would need to mount them as bind. Please tell in the comments section if that is the case.